# Can power of an electromagnet be changed like frequency of a motor is changed using VFD?

Tags: power, electromagnetic, variable

I am from a commerce background and am not technical. I want to use an electromagnet to lift up Iron and Steel but since I have a retail shop, I have to lift up varying quantity as per the demands of my customers from the whole lot I have. There are electromagnets working in iron and steel all over the globe but they all have fixed power. I want to know if it is possible to change the power of electromagnet using a regulator sort of a thing so that it may lift up only 100kg out of a lot of 10000 kg and also 2000kg out of the same lot as and when demanded. I am not looking to do it myself but want to know the possibility and if there is any specific device that helps do it like there is VFD for motors.

Comment: The amount of material it will glomp onto is going to depend a lot on the shape and characteristics of the material. I don't think you will be able to reliably lift predetermined amounts of material with such an electromagnet- but there is no reason why it could not be done.

Comment: Sorry Anuj but EMF (force) is proportional to current and when in motion produces Back EMF voltage and thus reduces current and thus force, EMF Force must exceed gravitational F=mg to stick. THus DC is strongest and VFD's must increase voltage with RPM or V/F = constant torque.

Comment: We are into MS Pipes. So we have pipes ranging from 1/2" to 4". The surface area is going to be less and moreover the top layer of the stack is going to be in direct contact of the magnet, the layer below it would only be in contact with top layer. Will this work?

Comment: Who knows but obviously less coupling force

Comment: @ Tony - I am not technical and could not understand but in layman terms, how can this be made possible or it isn't possible?

Comment: without a design and specs, it is impossible to judge  imagine a similar vague commerce question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible, for certain meanings of the word possible.

A VFD would not work. A constant current source **would** alter the strength of the magnet, and **would** allow it to pick up varying amounts of material.

Two problems.

a) It would not be easy to calibrate, or be very consistent. You would not be able to say 'X amps will pick up Y kg of material' with any degree of precision. The amount of stuff picked up be a magnet will depend on the configuration of the stuff. If it's a bit closer packed, then you'll be able to pick up a bit more. The best you can say is that generally, a weaker field will tend to pick up less stuff.

b) Where are you going to get one of these from, unless it's sold as the 'field control for a big magnet'? I don't know how much power your magnet dissipates at maximum input, but as you are talking about 2000kg of lift, I suspect a typical off-the-shelf controllable current lab power supply will not cut it. The principle is fairly straightforward, PWM and using the magnet's inductance to smooth out the current. However, it will need to be big enough, and at a reasonable switching frequency for the magnet, unless it's a full-blown buck SMPS in which case the switching frequency is less relevant.

Find, build or commission a switch-mode current source with enough power to cover your control range, and you're almost done.

Be aware that a magnet of this size will store a lot of energy, enough to trash an ordinary power supply if you try to turn the current off suddenly, or the input power supply fails! Whatever you use must be designed to handle this kick back without dying. Again the principle is simple enough, it's just the scale of the problem that requires the attention to safety.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to complicate things. If you already have the electromagnet, then use this for all amount of steel you wish to carry. You would need a constant DC current source, so that the electromagnet winding is excited with constant current. Larger current would produce stronger field and keep more heavy piece, but it will produce also larger amount of heat due to the resistive loss.

Keep in mind that energy is needed to grab the piece - mass and lifting distance matters. After that, no  energy is needed to hold the piece, in case we could have superconducting wire for the windings. Unfortunately, the copper winding will produce heat, which is an energy loss that has to be supplied from the power supply. But this energy waste is very small compared to the complexity you want to achieve and possible damage and injuries if the pieces fall on ground.

A very similar power supply would be the Arc Welder Inverter.